# pyodbc bulk Insert

Tags: pyodbc, bulkinsert, fillna

With SQL Server ODBC Driver 17, Object nulls is not an issue. But it gives error below on dates and integers

```
Invalid character value for cast specification (0) (SQLExecute)')
```

Process works fine when cursor.fast_executemany = False, or when default values (0, 1900-01-01) set for the null dates and integers.

Is there a way to bulk insert keeping the Nulls in place?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve].